# constructor function not showing correct results

Tags: javascript

i am a newbie here.
i am trying to create a car object and instances.
The code is

```
  function Car(name, speed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.describe=describeCar;
    };


    function describeCar(){
        document.write("The Full name is " + this.name + " and the top speed is " + this.speed);
    };

    var mercedes = new Car("Mercedes benz", 233); // Instance of Object
    var bmw = new Car("British motor Works", 260); // Instance of Object
    mercedes.describeCar();
```

Now i don't see anything in browser.
please tell me what i am doing wrong.
Thanks so much!.

Comment: `mercedes.describe();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the function reference `describeCar` to the `describe` property of `Car` so

```
mercedes.describe();
```

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini Take a while carefully debugging your code before coming to SO

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini: Best thanks on Stack Overflow are an upvote and accept, if you found an answer useful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vr0nLnue/2/ - Another way to use prototype object to achieve the same

Answer (score 1):

```
function Car(name, speed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.describe=describeCar;
    };


    function describeCar(){
        document.write("The Full name is " + this.name + " and the top speed is " + this.speed);
    };

    var mercedes = new Car("Mercedes benz", 233); // Instance of Object
    var bmw = new Car("British motor Works", 260); // Instance of Object
mercedes.describe();
```

**mercedes.describe();**

You should call the class function name not the defined one.

Answer (score -2):

describeCar is a function so need parenthesis to call it and "this" as reference if you want to use it inside the constructor:

```
function Car(name, speed) {
    this.name = name;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.describe=this.describeCar();
};

Car.prototype.describeCar = function(){
    return "The Full name is " + this.name + " and the top speed is " + this.speed;
};

var mercedes = new Car("Mercedes benz", 233); // Instance of Object
var bmw = new Car("British motor Works", 260); // Instance of Object
document.write(mercedes.describe);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nzv7jjch/

if you just need the function output then just call to the function and avoid using it in the constructor:

```
function Car(name, speed) {
    this.name = name;
    this.speed = speed;
};

Car.prototype.describeCar = function(){
    return "The Full name is " + this.name + " and the top speed is " + this.speed;
};

var mercedes = new Car("Mercedes benz", 233); // Instance of Object
var bmw = new Car("British motor Works", 260); // Instance of Object
document.write(mercedes.describeCar());
```

Comment: `this.describe=this.describeCar();` is very wrong: a) `this.describeCar` is not defined, so you cannot call it. b) At this point, the function should be **assigned** to `this.describe`, not called.

Comment: describeCar is defined while is being added to the existing prototype by using Car.prototype

Comment: Oh you are right, I missed that part. Still confusing though (as you can see, I was confused). The OP's intention was not to call the function in the constructor. They wanted to *assign* the function to `this.describe`. Also, the description *"describeCar is a function so need parenthesis to call it and "this" as reference if you want to use it inside the constructor:"*, targets *your* code, not the OP's code. The OP didn't need parenthesis because they didn't want to call the function. They also didn't need `this`, because the function was not assigned to the prototype.